# Undefined property:View::$title in <b>C:\.....\components\.....\views\...\tmpl\default.php

Tags: php, joomla, joomla2.5

I am seeing an undefined property warning PHP notice on my registration form in Joomla 2.5 , wondering whats causing this issue. Its happening on the lines which try to echo with `$this`

```
<?php if($this->title == 'Me'){echo "selected=\"selected\"";}?>>Me</option>
```

Update: $this in this case is referring to the correct class. Its the `$title` thats the issue which is prompting the undefined property issue. Whats the remedy to use variables in a php file which have not been defined yet?

Thanks.

Comment: you will need to provide more code to get an answer

Comment: This error occur due to this pointer refer to other class that are not the function exists.The this here is not taking actual required object.

Comment: @Lodder Yes I added more code.

Comment: @JobinJose Yes Got that part,I think reinstantiatinng the pointer would help here but unsure which class this object is trying to refer to.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As the message indicated that it is an undefined variable, after running xdebug I noticed that  it was not being set and that was the issue. Thus checking if the variable is set and only then using the variable would help.